# Add Custom Attributes to Existing View

Tags: java, android, android-view, androidplot

I am using AndroidPlot since a while and found out that their are serveral settings, that cannot be set using  xml.
Now during playing around with BindingAdapter, I created some Methodes to extend existing attributes with custom which are only provided Programmically.
Now my problem is that I have to bind something to the attributes in order to take effect.

So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to add xml-Attributes, using something simular 
   like BindingAdapters to Views.
2. Or is it possible to force android to use the BindingAdapter for     OneTimeBinding?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a ViewModel for the Diagramm, so I can check the States additionally using TDD and can use the BindingAdapter to add some xml Attributes.